# Mathematical keyboard with textarea (bugs)

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, textarea

I am not a programmer and I am learning HTML and programming in Javascrip currently. I'm very new to this and I don't know if my question will sound too silly. A friend and I decided to make a mathematical keyboard, it was difficult and we managed to get something good.

A problem that was very complicated to solve was the "loses caret position" and I think we were able to solve it. However, some buttons, when clicked in sequence or repeatedly more than two or three times, do not appear correctly and these undesirable question marks keep appearing in the textarea. Each browser responds in a different way and we suspect that each version of them also, as there are differences between my notebook (Windows 10 with Chrome, Firefox and Edge updated) and my friend's.

[image: question marks problem]

Below is the code of the function that we implemented to make the symbols appear when the buttons are clicked. The `myField.setSelectionRange (endPos + 1, endPos + 1)`
is our attempt to solve the "loses caret position" problem and it seemed to work in most cases.

```
    function imprime(myValue) {

    myField = document.getElementById("entrada")

    if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
        var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue.value + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    } else {
        myField.value += myValue.value;

    }
    myField.focus();
    myField.setSelectionRange(endPos+1, endPos+1);
}
```

We have already tried to modify some lines of code and researched if there was a problem with the fonts used in the html codes, but we have not been able to discover anything so far.

We have no idea what's going on and we wanted to know why these things keep happening and how to fix them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a font problem. It's a unicode string manipulation issue.

Javascript uses UTF-16 encoding. Some of the math characters are in Unicode supplementary plane 1, and in UTF-16 are represented using two 16-bit code units. Similarly, the DOM `setSelectionRange` API is also using UTF-16. The [spec for `setSelectionRange`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-textarea%2Finput-setselectionrange) indicates that it indexes on code units, not characters. To correctly select using that API, you need to account for the extra code units in any supplementary-plane characters.

So, what is happening is that, after a supplementary plane character is entered (represented with two code units), you are setting the caret position between the two code units. Then, when the next character is entered, it is splitting those two code units, and independently they are no longer valid character representations. They end up being displayed as �.